# Checkout, Fetch and Pull in BitBucket SourceTree

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, project-hosting

I am using **BitBucket** for web based hosting of our projects. Along with that I am using their **SourceTree** for committing and such purpose. I am a bit confused with the **Checkout**, **Fetch** and **Pull** option available in the SourceTree interface and their usage. Can someone familiar with this tool explains the usage of these options available in SourceTree?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Using [Atlassian's Git tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing) (link updated) as a reference.

**Git checkout**:

> The git checkout command lets you navigate between the branches
>   created by git branch. Checking out a branch updates the files in the
>   working directory to match the version stored in that branch, and it
>   tells Git to record all new commits on that branch. Think of it as a
>   way to select which line of development you’re working on.
>
> Source: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches#git-checkout

**Git pull**:

> You can think of git pull as Git's version of svn update. It’s an easy
>   way to synchronize your local repository with upstream changes. The
>   following diagram explains each step of the pulling process.
>
> Source: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing#git-pull

**Git fetch**:

> The git fetch command imports commits from a remote repository into
>   your local repo. The resulting commits are stored as remote branches
>   instead of the normal local branches that we’ve been working with.
>   This gives you a chance to review changes before integrating them into
>   your copy of the project.
>
> Source: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing#git-fetch

Comment: How I can "review changes before integrating them into your copy of the project."? I don't see this option in SourceTree.

Comment: Fetch brings down information about the commits to a remote branch. You can examine those commits in the view pane.